# Antlr symbols - Need examples

Tags: parsing, token, antlr, symbols

I am looking at a code base where Antlr is used and many grammars are defined. I see the following being used but not clear what they actually mean

> 1. token {ONE, TWO}

- I dont see ONE or TWO defined anywhere.

> 2. Symbols -> and ^

- Whats the purpose of these? I see these in both the lexer and the parser rules

> 3. Symbol []

- This is used in the following

token {SET}

ID : ...

TOKEN1 : .. SET[$ID]

What does this mean? Examples would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

These items look as if they come from an ANTLR3 grammar. The first part is probably a tokens section (note the plural), like this:

```
tokens {
  ONE,
  TWO
}
```

which defines a number of "virtual" tokens. These are called "virtual" because they have no input to match and are usually used in tree rewriting (e.g. changing a tokens type depending on some conditions, e.g. the outcome of a predicate).

The symbols `->` and `^` are used for tree rewriting when generating an AST (and are no longer supported by ANTLR4 btw, because it doesn't produce an AST at all, but a parse tree). `^` denotes a root node, which causes the parser to create a tree of the current tokens in the active rule and use the marked token as the root of that tree. `->` allows to rewrite the result even more (different order, add virtual tokens, leave out tokens etc.).

And the last part of your question demonstrates the use of token manipulation. This syntax causes the parser to create a new token SET with all the values (except the type, but e.g. the source position, channel etc.) from the matched ID token. So it's also part of the rewriting machinery.

**Update**:
The ANTLR3 homepage is still alive and has a Wiki with some documentation: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR+3+Wiki+Home (or via http://www.antlr3.org).

Comment: @MikeThanks. That helps to an extent for sure but can you point me to some examples which describes these. Examples would make things even better.

Comment: All these things are described in the definitive ANTLR3 guide. This is the ultimative reference for everybody working seriously with ANTLR3 (same for ANTLR4 btw). There is no concise summary I know of which describes all that. Usually you take other grammars and learn from examples. I added a link to my answer.